# Estimation of eigenfunctions of a Covariance operator

Tags: st.statistics

I'm currently working with the book "Inference for Functional Data with Applications" by Horáth and Kokoszka and trying to understand Hilbert space models for functional data. At the moment I'm trying to understand the basics of estimating the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a covariance operator $Cy = \int\limits_0^1 c(t,s)y(s) \, ds$ with $y \in L^2([0,1])$ and $c$ a kernel function.

The eigenfunctions $v_j$ are defined by $Cv_j = \lambda_j v_j$ with $||v_j|| = 1$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_j$. So we have $\int\limits_0^1 \hat{c}(t,s) \hat{v}_j(s) \, ds = \hat{\lambda_j}\hat{v_j}$ with $\hat{v}_j$ estimate of $v_j$, $\hat{\lambda_j}$ estimate of $\lambda_j$ and $\hat{c}(t,s)$ estimate of covariance function $c(t,s)$.

The book says "If $\hat{v_j}$ is an estimate computed from the data, we can only hope that $\hat{c_j} \hat{v_j}$ is close to $v_j$, where $\hat{c_j} =$ sign$( \langle \hat{v_j}, v_j \rangle)$"
This $\hat{c_j}$ confuses me. The estimation of $v_j$ is $\hat{v_j}$. So for what reason is the $\hat{c_j}$ necessary?
Furthermore the book says "Note that $\hat{c_j}$ cannot be computed form [sic] the data, so it must be ensured that the statistics we want to work with do not depend on $\hat{c_j}$." So we also can't estimate $\hat{c_j}$, as we don't know $v_j$. Can't it be just ignored then?